# use of <> in php and in wamp

Tags: php, wamp

This must be terribly well known, but I can't find anything relevant. Strings in php cant have the characters `<` and `>` in them in the wamp environment. It all works fine in the live server. e g under wamp

```
$teststring = 'aaa<bbb';
echo $teststring;
```

produces  `aaa`.

I want to edit html files using `str_replace()` and `preg_replace()`.
I guess I have to modify the php set up but I don't know how.

Comment: View the page's source code

Comment: And what exactly is your question ? If you view the output in a browser, it will interpret `<bbb` as an html tag, so it won't be displayed...

Comment: You should explain your question with a bit more context. It is currently very confusing especially since it's not clear what environments you are refering to, see also my answer below.

Comment: Balder-dash the `<` is just another character unless you try an view it in a browser when it will look to the browser like you started an HTML tag and didnt complete it, a `<b>` in this case and forgot the closing `>`

Comment: Use `&gt;` (Greater than..) or `&lt;` (Less than) if you want to add the `<>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume it doesn't have anything to do with WAMP, and I'm not even sure I understand the situation fully, because you say "Strings in php cant have the characters <> in them in the wamp environment" (I interpret it as: It doesn't work with WAMP) and then directly afterwards "It all works fine in the live server. e g under wamp" (I interpret it as: It does work with WAMP).

But I believe the problem is just that you are adding stray unencoded `<`'s into the HTML output. Think about what would happen normally:

```
<?php echo "I can write <em>emphasized</em> text!"; ?>
```

...would result in:

> I can write *emphasized* text!

...and not:

> `I can write <em>emphasized</em> text!`

Because you can output HTML from PHP, and the browser will read it as it would read any static HTML page. Now if you just include a random `<`, it will be interpreted as HTML as [said in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36862919/use-of-in-php-and-in-wamp#comment61293384_36862919) and will not be valid.

So, in order to have a literal `<` shown in the browser, it has to be encoded as HTML entity, in this case `&lt;`, e.g. `3 &lt; 4` instead of `3 < 4`. This can be automatically done using the function `htmlentities`. For example:

```
<?php echo htmlentities("This is a string with < and > and & and other stuff like this which has to be encoded."); ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, in my ignorance I didn't know <> could have meaning in a string, and I understand why the tests using wamp and echo wont work. I was trying to simplify the testing. I am using php code under wamp  to edit html files using str_replace and preg_replace. I must apply the edits to the actual html and check the results. Thanks again

Comment: If you just want to see raw output from your PHP file, without having the browser interpret it as HTML, you can either use the "View page source" option in your browser or add this at the beginning of your file (it will tell the browser to interpret your output as plain text): `header("Content-Type: text/plain");` - And just to clarify, `<`/`>` don't have any meaning inside a string in PHP itself. PHP just outputs them, and your browser is the one who tries to seek meaning in it (not PHP).

Comment: I ve ticked the answer from CherryDT, more answers are not necessary, they are a bit embarrassing!! I m a 76 year old writing his first website!Not sure what else I have to do to kill off the question. dnjfer